# Search markers by title on Google Maps with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3

I'm retrieving markers from web service using an AJAX method and I'd like to search them on the map using the marker property title. Is it possible?

This is my function thats returns the markers:

```
function displayLocation(location) {

            var content =   '<strong>'  + location.name + '</strong>';
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.coordinate[0]), parseFloat(location.coordinate[1]));
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: position,
                title: location.name,
                url: 'https://www.google.com.br/#q=' + location.name,
                icon: 'img/restaurant_pin.png'
            });

            var label = new Label({
              map: map
            });
            label.bindTo('position', marker);
            label.bindTo('text', marker, 'title');
            label.bindTo('visible', marker);
            label.bindTo('clickable', marker);
            label.bindTo('zIndex', marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              window.location.href = marker.url;
            });


    }
```

Comment: Add all your markers to an array. Loop through your array and see if the current marker title matches your search.

Comment: They are on an Array. But I'm trying to doing that, but it's not working. Do you have any ideia how to start writing it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @Danilo Brizola did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `markers` is your array of markers and `yourSearchPhrase` is what you are searching for:

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

    if (markers[i].title == yourSearchPhrase) {

        // this marker's title equals your search phrase
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it search for marker titles in map and directs the location to searched title?

Comment: `map.setCenter(markers[i].getPosition());` will center the map on the matching marker if you add this in the `if` condition of the above code.

Comment: Can we do same functionality with autocmplete suggestion feature?Means if i type in search box i get suggestions in dropdown with all the data coming from markers array?If you know any can you send me link or something?

Comment: What autocomplete? Places Autocomplete is for searching in Google Places. If you want to search within your own data you need another solution.